# Javascript array built dynamically in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I have an array, say

```
var arr = ["id", "currency", "region", "status"]
```

How can I map the above to an object literal, as below?

```
var columns = [
      { key:"id",        headerRenderer:"id" },
      { key:"currency",  headerRenderer:"currency" },
      { key:"status",    headerRenderer:"region" },
      { key:"region",    headerRenderer:"status" }
    ];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var 1` is a syntax error.

Comment: No, I flipped them by mistake. And thanks for the tip with var,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.The provided function is a `callback`.

So, as I said above `map` method provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. The elements from the `result` array are `objects`, like this: `{"key":item, "headerRenderer":item}`.

```js
var array = ["id", "currency", "region", "status"]
var columns=array.map(function(item){
    return {
      "key":item,
      "headerRenderer":item
    }
});
console.log(columns);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [map method on the Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) allows you to apply a function to every element in an array, thereby effectively abstracting iteration for simple cases. Your case is simple, because the content of any entry in `result` is completely specified by its corresponding entry in `arr`, which means you can "map"

```
"id" --> { key: "id", headerRenderer: "id" }
```

Using map you can solve your problem in just one line (provided your environment supports ES6):

```js
var arr = ["id", "currency", "region", "status"]

var result = arr.map(key => ({ key, headerRenderer: key }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var columns = [];
var array = ["id", "currency", "region", "status"];

for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
  columns.push({
    key: array[i],
    headerRenderer: array[i]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally `.map()` is the way but another functional approach would be to use a tail call recursive map as follows;

```js
var arr = ["id", "currency", "region", "status"],
   mapo = (a, r=[]) => a.length ? mapo(a.slice(1),r.concat({key:a[0],headerRenderer:a[0]})) : r;
console.log(mapo(arr));
```